# GETTING AN ERROR 'ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING' WHILE USING SQUID PROXY in Chrome. Otherwise the site is working fine in Internet

Tags: proxy

GETTING AN ERROR 'ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING' WHILE USING SQUID PROXY in Chrome. In other browsers, the page is not getting loaded. If proxy is not used the site is working fine in Internet.
The issue happens only where machines are connected through Squid proxy

Comment: Versions? Configuration? Maybe some response headers? For now I can say that you probably have invalid chunked encoding :D

Comment: The SQUID version is squid-2.6.STABLE21.3.el5. But many other users are working in internet and other networks with out any issue. Our application is developed in codeigniter with mysql DB

Answer (score 0):

`squid-2.6.STABLE21.3.el5` doesn't fully support `HTTP 1.1`. Genrally it responds to `HTTP 1.1` requests with `HTTP 1.0` response. That is the problem. There are two ways to resolve it:

**Solution 1**

> There is an experimental patch to add partial HTTP/1.1 support to
>   Squid-2 at http://devel.squid-cache.org/. This might work for you unless
>   your site is accepting POST/PUT requests.. (100-Continue is not yet
>   supported).

**Solution 2**

> I heard that version 3.1 fully supports `HTTP 1.1`.
>
> **Please note that version 3.0 does not!**